# Could not find asset

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I link js file in example/index.html this way:

```
<script src="../lib/src/myjsfile.js"></script>
```

I run app this way:

```
pub serve example
```

And I got in CLI:

> [example] GET lib/src/myjsfile.js => Could not find asset mod_lib|example/lib/src/myjsfile.js.

It looks for assets in example directory and ignores part "../".
How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you please try `<script src="packages/mod_lib/src/myjsfile.js"></script>`

Comment: it fixes the issue. But: 1) there no any "packages" directory 2) It's not spoted in docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead a package path

```
<script src="packages/mod_lib/src/myjsfile.js"></script>
```

Every file outside the `lib/` directory that imports a file from within the `lib/` directory needs to use a package import.
`dart2js` also recognizes package imports in above form and replaces them with the actual path in the build output directory.

I created https://github.com/dart-archive/www.dartlang.org/issues/1593

`packages` was a real directory in earlier Dart versions that contained a symlink to `../lib` (and all other dependencies specified in `pubspec.yaml`). A while ago it was replaced by the content of the `.packages` file. You'll find an entry for the current packages name with a path to the `lib` directory (and also all dependencies from `pubspec.yaml` with a path to the download directory in `~/.pub-cache`).